# Changing color of vector layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, color

Is it possible to change the color while adding a vector layer?

I have a vector layer with water areas and want to load it with a blue color style. The layer is added with:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.vlayer)
```

Can I change the color after or while loading?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
symbols = self.vlayer.rendererV2().symbols()
symbol = symbols[0]
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(50,50,250))
```

Answer (score 7):

Finally with this code the change of a layer color is working for me:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.vlayer)       
symbols = self.vrlayer.rendererV2().symbols()
symbol = symbols[0]
symbol.setColor(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(50,50,250))
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh() 
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(self.vlayer)
```

You have to reload the MapCanvas and the layers panel aswell.

Comment: What module do you need to load to get access to rendererV2()?

Comment: @user2627043 and those trying to reuse old examples: Like many answers here, this one is outdated. As of today, color can be changed by: `vlayer.renderer().symbol().setColor(QColor.fromRgb(50,50,250))`. See also [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/331412/201000).