# How to get the color of a vector layer in pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, color

I have see this topic ([How to change the color of a vector layer in pyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70058/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-vector-layer-in-pyqgis/70112#70112)) but I'm looking for get the color not to change.

How I can resolve my problem ?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to provide more details about what you are trying to do, please?

Comment: It's ok, I have solve my problem with : layer.rendererV2().symbol().color()

Comment: You could still improve your question and post your own answer. You came here looking for help and so are other people.