# Creating gradient-filled rectangle in PyQGIS layout?

Tags: pyqgis, vector

I have created a print layout with some of the layers of my QGIS Project using PyQGIS. I am trying to add a gradient filled rectangle to the layout. In the GUI, I would use the "Add Shape" --> "Add Rectangle" tool, drag the shape to the desired location, and use the "Item Properties" to fill with a gradient. However, I am having difficulties reproducing the shape programmatically.

To create the Layout, I use the following code:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layoutName = "Some_name"

# The next step allows the script to run multiple times without naming issues
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)

layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)
```

After having added my layers, I tried to add a polygon:

```py
# Make a polygon from coordinates (in layout)
# The coordinates are in the layout units
xmin = 20
xmax = 40
ymin = 20
ymax = 60
polygon = QPolygonF()
polygon.append(QPointF(xmin, ymin))
polygon.append(QPointF(xmax, ymin))
polygon.append(QPointF(xmax, ymax))
polygon.append(QPointF(xmin, ymax))

# Create the polygon from nodes
polygonItem = QgsLayoutItemPolygon(polygon, layoutname)

# Add to the layout
layout.addItem(polygonItem)

# Style properties
props = {}
props["color"] = "green"
props["style"] = "solid"
props["style_border"] = "solid"
props["color_border"] = "black"
props["width_border"] = "0.26"
props["joinstyle"] = "miter"

# Create symbolfiller from properties
symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple(props)
polygonItem.setSymbol(symbol)
```

This approach allows me to create a filled polygon. I cannot find the method to fill the polygon with a gradient, and I haven't yet found the list of options that can be set in the parameter dictionary. I also tried to replace the `QgsFillSymbol` with `QgsGradientFillSymbolLayer`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

After you defined `symbol`, just add the following line immediately after to create a gradient brush style:

```
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setBrushStyle(Qt.BrushStyle(Qt.FDiagPattern))
```

---

So it looks like:

```
# Create symbolfiller from properties
symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple(props)
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setBrushStyle(Qt.BrushStyle(Qt.FDiagPattern))
polygonItem.setSymbol(symbol)
```

---

You can check the method of looking at other properties in this post: [Change vector layer symbology PyQGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331408/change-vector-layer-symbology-pyqgis-3)

Comment: I can fill the rectangle with hashed lines (Qt.FDiagPattern), or a solid color, but I cannot get a linear gradient to work. I have tried with Qt.LinearGradientPattern, but cannot set the colors, leaving the rectangle blank. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @MaximL - Try using something like `symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeColor(QColor(255,255,1))` to set the stroke colour.