# Change the border colour and line width of a polygon with pyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon

I have worked out how to change the color of a polygon using pyQGIS but cannot change the stroke color or line with based on the questions detailed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331408/change-vector-layer-symbology-pyqgis-3) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255320/increasing-size-and-changing-color-in-centroids-lines-and-polygons).  My example code below that works to make the polygon transparent fill but not for the blue border and desired linewidth.

```
# Attach core modules 
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
from qgis.core import *                        # attach main QGIS library
from qgis.utils import *                       # attach main python library
import os                                      # attach operating system library
import processing

# Set the working directory - recommended to use unix forward slash for path
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
wd = "C:/TEST"      # Set work directory
os.chdir(wd)                                              # Change the directory
os.getcwd()                                               # Confirm change

# Set a variable for the current project instance
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Prj = QgsProject.instance()                         # Object for current project

# Save the project to this file name
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pnm = "200924_Test.qgs"                      # Project file name
pnm = wd + "/" + pnm                               # Concat. with path
Prj.write(pnm)                                     # Save the project

# Create an array [] object with the polygon vertices for MRE model area
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
vrtcs = []
vrtcs.append(QgsPointXY(541600,6504400))
vrtcs.append(QgsPointXY(541600,6505100))
vrtcs.append(QgsPointXY(542160,6505100))
vrtcs.append(QgsPointXY(542160,6504400))

# Create a polygon from the vertices
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ply_01 = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([vrtcs])

# Create a feature object then append the polygon into the feature
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ftr = QgsFeature()
ftr.setGeometry(ply_01)
print(ftr.geometry())

# Create a  layer for the feature, in the desired CRS  28351  GDA94/MGA 51
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lyr = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:28351', '200924_MRE_Area',"memory")
Prj.addMapLayers([lyr])

# Make the layer editable, add the feature with the polygon and save the layer
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lyr.startEditing()
lyr.addFeature(ftr)
lyr.commitChanges()

# Save as a shapefile
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Fl_ou = 'Test'
Fl_ou = wd + '/' + Fl_ou

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"

# Change the fill, stroke colour and line width of the the polygon
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rndr = lyr.renderer()                   # object to change rendering
rndr.dump()                             # report current rendering

sym = rndr.symbol()                     # object to change the symbology of layer
syms = sym[0]                           # use first layer in QGIS tree
syms.setColor(QColor("transparent"))                 # remove the fill colour            
syms.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeColor(QColor("blue"))   # change the stroke colour (Fails)
syms.symbolLayer(0).setWidth(3)                      #
lyr.triggerRepaint()                                 # Refresh canvas
```

Additionally, the questions (linked) also suggest the following lines of code should be included at the end of this process - I would like to understand why they are required

```
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the following two lines from:

```
syms.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeColor(QColor("blue"))   # change the stroke colour (Fails)
syms.symbolLayer(0).setWidth(3)                      #
```

to:

```
syms.setStrokeColor(QColor("blue"))
syms.setStrokeWidth(3)
```

and it should work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - when I use syms.setStrokeColor(QColor,("blue")) I get a new error as follows > syms.setStrokeColor(QColor,("blue"))   # change the stroke colour FAILS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: setStrokeColor(self, strokeColor: Union[QColor, Qt.GlobalColor]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same code you posted? I just copy and paste your code and changed the two lines that I posted, and everything is okay, as you can see in the answer. I think this is related to another line. It shows the error at line 90. Please check that line.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick feedback - you are correct it works in the stripped-down version I posted - must be something else I've done in the main code - have a good day!